# Why can't I use float numbers instead of integers?

Tags: python, pygame, pycharm

```
import pygame
import random

pygame.init()

# create screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 600))

# Title + Logo
pygame.display.set_caption("Space Invader")
icon = pygame.image.load("chicken.png")
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

# Player icon
player_icon = pygame.image.load("spaceship.png")
playerX = 400
playerY = 500

player_changeX = 0
player_changeY = 0

# enemy Player
enemy_icon = pygame.image.load("space-invaders.png")
enemyX = random.randint(0, 936)
enemyY = random.randint(-100, -50)

enemy_changeX = random.randint (0.1, 0.5)
enemy_changeY = random.randint (0.1, 0.5)

if enemyY >= 500:
    print("Game over")
    exit()


def player(x, y):
    screen.blit(player_icon, (x, y))


def enemy(x, y):
    screen.blit(enemy_icon, (x, y))


# game loop
running = True
while running:

    # backround colour  RGB
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            # If key pressed check whether its right or left
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player_changeX = -1
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player_changeX = 1
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                player_changeY = -1
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                player_changeY = 1
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player_changeX = 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                player_changeY = 0
    # If player reaches boarder
    if playerX >= 936:
        playerX = 20
    if playerX <= 0:
        playerX = 936
    if playerY <= 0:
        playerY = 0
    if playerY >= 550:
        playerY = 550
    # enemy control
    if enemyX >= 936:
        enemyX = 20
    if enemyX <= 0:
        enemyX = 936
    if enemyY <= 0:
        enemyY = 0
    if enemyY >= 550:
        enemyY = random.randint(-100, -50)

    # Player change in coordinates
    playerX += player_changeX
    playerY += player_changeY

    #enemy change in coordinates
    enemyX += enemy_changeX
    enemyY += enemy_changeY

    #Results
    player(playerX, playerY)
    enemy(enemyX, enemyY)
    pygame.display.update()
```

I just got into programing, I am creating a little game. It's not finished yet but I am running into a problem I want to use float numbers instead of integers but it doesn't let me. Can you change this? and if yes how. The flaot number i want to use is in enemy_changeX and Y. 
The error it's giving me is ,

line 212, in randrange
    raise ValueError("non-integer arg 1 for randrange()")
ValueError: non-integer arg 1 for randrange()

even though I don't have a line 212

I hope the question was accurate enough.

Comment: `enemy_changeX = random.randint (0.1, 0.5)` You're asking for an integer between 0.1 and 0.5. Has it occurred to you that that's mathematically impossible?

Comment: I know you can't get an integer between 0.1 and 0.5, how can i ask for a float

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are requesting an integer between `0.1` and `0.5`, which is not possible for obvious reasons.

To get a `float` you can use `random.uniform(0.1, 0.5)`.

Although I have to note here, that pixels can't be float values, because there are no half pixels. Thus you have to think whether you really need a float value for a pixel change value.

Comment: I will. It's say's i can do it in 2 min